# Splitting observable payload into multiple observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, apollo-client

I have an Apollo query that I pipe through a map operator to emit objects. For example, `{name: "doron", color: "red"}`.

```
query$ = this.apollo.watchQuery(query)
```

I want to split it into 2 observables - `name$` and `color$` so that `name$` emits the name values and `color$` emits the color values.

What we do today is this:

```
name$ = new Subject();
color$ = new Subject();
query$.valueChanges.subscribe(p => {
  name$.next(p.name);
  color$.next(p.color);
})
```

This is not ideal because we need to manually unsubscribe. Also, it subscribes to the query before any of the "child" observables is being subscribed to.

How can I do this without subscribing to the query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While both Fan and Dallows have good answers, I think a mix of both + a slight tweak would be nice:

```js
query$ = query.pipe(
  // You won't subscribe to `query` twice (or more).
  shareReplay({

    // If one of the observables (`query$`, `name$` or `color$`) are subscribed to later on,
    // you'll get instantly the last value that was emitted 
    // (compared to `share` which wouldn't give you the last value if you subscribe too late).
    bufferSize: 1,

    // Whenever the number of subscribers to the query falls down to 0, it'll automatically unsubscribe from that observable as well.
    refCount: true
  })
);

name$ = query$.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(({name}) => name)
);
color$ = query$.valueChanges.pipe(
  map(({color}) => color)
);
```

*(The explanation below are also written as a comment in the code above)*

Using `shareReplay`, you won't subscribe to `query` twice (or more).

Thanks to `bufferSize: 1`, if one of the observables (`query$`, `name$` or `color$`) are subscribed to later on, you'll get instantly the last value that was emitted (compared to `share` which wouldn't give you the last value if you subscribe too late).

Thanks to `refCount: true`, whenever the number of subscribers to the query falls down to 0, it'll automatically unsubscribe from that observable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating partial observables as `Subjects` and pushing to them, create them directly by mapping from the query.

```typescript
name$ = query.valueChanges.pipe(map(({name}) => name));
color$ = query.valueChanges.pipe(map(({color}) => color));
```

You can then easily unsubscribe them separately or use in `async` pipe. I created a little showcase, to illustrate how it works: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-idgitr?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: What will happen when we subscribe to each observable? Wouldn't that trigger the query twice?

Comment: You are subscribing to `valueChanges`, subscribing to it does not trigger the change. So it's safe

Answer (score 0):

You can share the OQ observable and use [`pluck`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/pluck) to get your value

```js
const oq = query$.valueChanges.pipe(share());

let name$ = oq.pipe(pluck('name'));
let color$ = oq.pipe(pluck('color'))
```

Comment: While this is a great solution the problem is that it’s not type safe (to my knowledge) in case you have Typescript, @dallows in the other hand is type safe

Comment: pluck or using map doesn't ensure type safety at runtime. Typescript only guard type at compile time. So to 100% type safe, we will have to add type checking function

Comment: You’re right, my bad. I thought that map change the type

Comment: On a second look I don’t think I’m wrong, look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kasbxm?file=src/app/app.component.ts) StackBlitz, it gives an error when the subject is number type and not a string, you could also look at the source code of `map` [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/f20a48af0db1969c564514f6c5a7bd75bd5dcb66/src/internal/operators/map.ts#L46)

Comment: I know, that’s what I meant, compile time, this is why I said it will be beneficial if you have typescript, as far as I’m concerned , `pluck` doesn’t give that type safety